# 5V and Vin pin in Arduino UNO

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, power-supply, voltage, arduino-uno

I am trying to control the speed of a DC motor by using H-Bridge and Arduino UNO. The initial supply is 110 AC which with the help of transformer and a full wave rectifier circuit is converted into 12V DC supply. This 12V is given to the H-Bridge. Now with the help of Buck Converter, the 12V is stepped down to 5V. Now my question is that this 5V, should I use the 5V pin or the Vin pin in Arduino?

Comment: It seems that only the last sentence is relevant to your question.

Comment: So will I use the 5V pin in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a regulated 5V to power your Arduino you would connect it to the 5V pin. When doing so make sure there is no connection to the USB connector or to the DC Barrel Power connector.